# How do I get the value from this arraylist and display the text containing it?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, andengine

I found this setup for an inventory, but how can I get a list of whats in the inventory to show the user, and how do I remove an item if they drop or use it? And last, what is the best way to associate each item with a class containing its stats?

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

// HashMap with arrayLists of items by ID.
public static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> items = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
// Backpack with a slightly different structure.
public static HashMap<Integer, String> backpack = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creating the arrayLists.
    ArrayList<String> boots = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> swords = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> rings = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> daggers = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> bows = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Adding content to them...
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        boots.add("Boot" + i.toString());
        swords.add("Sword" + i.toString());
        rings.add("Ring" + i.toString());
        daggers.add("Dagger" + i.toString());
        bows.add("Bow" + i.toString());
    }

    // Putting the arrayLists to the HashMap of items by their IDs.
    items.put(ID.BOOTS, boots); items.put(ID.SWORDS, swords);
    items.put(ID.RINGS, rings); items.put(ID.DAGGERS, daggers);
    items.put(ID.BOWS, bows);

    // Printing all the content in all arrayLists in all IDs.
    for (ArrayList<String> e : items.values()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
            if (e.get(i)!=null) {
                System.out.println(e.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    // Here you could add any item to the backpack.
    // backpack.put(ID.SWORDS, swords.get(0));
}

public class ID {

    //Defining constant-IDs.
    public static final int BOOTS = 0;
    public static final int SWORDS = 1;
    public static final int RINGS = 2;
    public static final int DAGGERS = 3;
    public static final int BOWS = 4;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the HashMap, Item corresponds to the inventory and backpack corresponds to a user. The simplest thing you could do is to have a super class or an interface representing an item and to keep the counts. If you can inherit from it to use for every item, and process the counts for it, it would be useful. Similarly, have a class for representing the inventory with corresponding item subclasses and objects in it.

Something like this will work for Item,

```
 public class Item
 {
        String itemName;
        int initialStock;
        int currentStock;

    public int getInitialStock(){

         return initialStock();

    }

    public void setInitialStock(int initialStock){

             this.initialStock=initialStock;

   }
        //Other getters and setters too.
 }


 public class Sword extends Item{

      // You can use Item's methods for the statistics calculation.



 }
```

For inventory,

```
  public  class Inventory{

    HashMap<Integer,Item> itemMap; // To represent all items in inventory

    public void setItemMap(HashMap<Integer,Item> itemMap){

             this.itemMap=itemMap;
    }

  }
```

If you create an object of this Inventory class and add item number and corresponding items to the map, then the variable itemMap represents your stock for all items.

For example,

```
    public Inventory initialiseInventory(){
       Inventory inventoryObj=new Inventory();
       HashMap<Integer,Item> itemMap=new HashMap<Integer,Item>;


       Sword swordObj=new Sword();
       Rings ringsObj=new Rings();


       swordObj.setInitialStock(100);//100 swords in place
       ringsObj.setInitialStcok(200);//200 rings in place


       itemMap.put(ID.SWORDS,swordObj);
       itemMap.put(ID.RINGS,ringsObj);

       inventoryObj.setItemMap(itemMap);

       return inventoryObj;
    }


    public viewInventory(Inventory inventory){

    for(Entry<Integer,Item> itemEntry:inventory.itemMap.entrySet()){

           Item itemObj=itemEntry.getValue();
           System.out.println(itemObj.getItemName());
           System.out.println("---------------------------------");
           System.out.println(itemObj.getInitialStock());
           System.out.println(itemObj.getCurrentStock());

        }
    }

   Now, you can to represent removal of an item, you can reduce the count for that particular item. This is a skeleton, you can improve on it.
```

Comment: So how would I call to view what items are in the inventory, or to call, say, slot one?

Comment: And how to call a texture for it, or create a new object based on it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using too many Arraylist with generic types create a Pojo class with setters and getters for the inventory. It will reduce application weightage and can be displayed in a listview using adapter class. From the listview we can delete item by getting the position

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create classes for each item, you can add an ID field also then you won't need a HashMap.

```
public class Inventory{

   Item boots = new Item(101, "boots", 5, 4); \\ 101 is the id
   Item swords ....

   ArrayList<Item> stock = new ArrayList<Item>();
   stock.add(boots);  


}
```

This is a just a start. I've included some tutorials on ArrayLists and HashMaps which might help too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU5ACV5MucM - Collections & ArrayList
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JOSjIan2g0 - HashMap